# How to detect collisions for multiple copies of kinematicbody2d node but with different extents of collisionshape2d?

Tags: collision-detection, game-physics, godot, gdscript

I have a problem in detecting collisions in my game.

The game has an Enemy scene (kinematicbody2d) that has a function for  assigning rectangle shape to the collisionshape2d

```
func set_collision(extents):
    var collision = $Collision
    var rect_shape = RectangleShape2D.new()
    rect_shape.extents = extents
    collision.shape = rect_shape
```

This function is called inside initialize function.

```
func initialize(start_position, ptexture, pspeed,
     ppower, collision_extents):
    position = start_position
    $Sprite.texture = ptexture
    speed = pspeed
    power = ppower
    set_collision(collision_extents)
```

I am using this function inside a Spawner scene to define multiple enemies with different properties.

```
func spawn_enemy():
    var enemy = enemy_scene.instance()
    var type = randi() % 4
    spawn_positions.shuffle()
    var random_position = spawn_positions[0].position
    
    match type:
        TYPES.BLACK:
            enemy.initialize(random_position, enemy_black,
             50, 4, Vector2(30, 23))
        TYPES.RED:
            enemy.initialize(random_position, enemy_red,
             100, 3, Vector2(30, 23))
    
    var main = get_tree().current_scene
    main.add_child(enemy)
```

What happens is when the bullet from the player misses the first enemy (e.g. black one), the following black enemies can't be killed (queue free from scene).

However, if the player kills the first enemy, he can kill the following ones.

Answer (score 0):

None of this was wrong.

The problem was in the function `_on_Bullet_body_enter(body)`

I was checking body by name using `body.name == "Enemy"` but sounds that this name is changing when multiple copies enter the scene.

I used `is_in_group("enemies")` and it worked fine.